# Stop redhat changing mac address when changing host in hyper v 2012

Tags: redhat, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

We have a Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster with three hosts. We have a Redhat vm in the cluster that can freely migrate between the three hosts. But every time the vm migrates to a different host and reboots for any reason, the ethernet interface in the vm changes and the vm loses connectivity.

The below picture is a screenshot of ifconfig -a command from the first time the vm turns on, with the correct ethernet configuration and ip addresses.
[image]

The below picture is a screenshot of the file /etc/udev.rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules from the first time the vm turns on.
[image]

The below picture is a screenshot of ifconfig -a command after the vm migrates to a different host and reboots.

[image]

And the picture below is from the same file after the vm migrates to a different host and reboots.
[image]

We need that the vm keeps the same ethernet configuration eth0 and eth1 every time that move to a different host and roboot. Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't it be the hypervisor to be blamed for changing the nic's mac address rather than the poor VM inheriting the value provided by the hypervisor? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/hyper-v-and-dynamic-mac-address-regeneration , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jhoward/hyper-v-mac-address-allocation-and-apparent-network-issues-mac-collisions-can-cause

Comment: Hi A.B, yes I should blame the hypervisor. But, if I assign a static mac address to the vm, once the vm migrates to a different host, it will lose communication because it is not in the same range as the host mac address, as described in your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in most VM Hosts, the MAC is dynamically assigned and usually changes on reboot or host migration. You can usually set a static MAC for a VM. You may need to change some settings about your VM environment to allow the MAC to migrate in the networking environment such as enabling MAC spoofing and forged transmits.

1. In Hyper-V or Failover Cluster Manager, edit the settings for your VM.
2. Go to the "Network Adapter" and expand to the "Advanced Features".
3. Change the "MAC Address" Radio button to "Static" versus "Dynamic". You'll need to provide the MAC address, but you should be able to put the current one.

For a RHEL/CentOS system, you may need to modify the NIC configuration to allow MAC changes to the NIC. See below.

4. Open the Redhat vm and edit ifcfg-ethx (x is the interface number) file if needed. Run command "vi /etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-ethx" and change all lines with HWADDR to #HWADDR

[image]

5. Move 70-persistent-net.rules file to a temp folder to allow regeneration of the file in the next reboot. Create a temp foler "mkdir /home/tmp-net-rules" and move the file "mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"
6. Reboot the vm "reboot"

Comment: Hi @duct_tape_coder, thank you for your answer. I was able to fix it with your answer. I also found a couple of other configurations that I had to do inside the RedHat vm in order to make it work completely. I would like to edit your answer to add those configurations as well.

Comment: Go ahead, then mark as answer please =)